# Visualizing a Curve Drawn on Plane Model of Sphere

Tags: general-topology, cw-complexes

The following is an image from Sue Goodman's $Beginning$ $Topology$.

[image]

My question: if I were to draw this on the space model of the sphere, am I correct that it would section the sphere into equally sized octants, with the center circle in the plane model corresponding to the equator? If not, what $does$ it look like?

Sorry that this is more of a "sanity check" than an actual question, but Goodman provides no solutions for her exercises so I thought I would confer with the Math.SE community instead.

Comment: You are correct. Indeed, this is what you get if you project an inscribed octahedron onto the sphere.